# Checking the contents of a Firebase/Realtime Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following code to check for new contents in Firebase / Database.
It is basically working. But when the contents is empty the code crashes.

What is the proper way to handle the case where postDict is coming back empty?
Is there some error code that we can be checked.

I have tried to check the value of postDict.count, but with no result.

```
FIRDatabaseHandle resultHandle =
[dbRef observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
                    withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                        NSDictionary *postDict = snapshot.value;
                        NSManagedObject *artWorkRcd;
                        for (NSString* artKey in postDict) {
                            // Some useful code.
                            .......
                        }
                    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIRDataSnapshot has a method called [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-exists) that returns YES if there is actually data in the snapshot.  You should check this before using `snapshot.value`.